# Java applet just displays grey when ran on webpage

Tags: java, applet, html

So for an assignment I had to make a little Java applet and display it on a webpage. It builds just fine in NetBeans, but when I try to run it in a webpage it displays gray, like this: http://devii.in/7apW The .jar file on my hard drive loads perfectly fine, so I'm confused as to what is messing it up. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

You can view it here yourself: http://trainman1405.com/hi.html
The jar: http://trainman1405.com/Apples.jar

My code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Apples extends JApplet  {
    private static void display() {
        JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField field2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField field3 = new JTextField();
        JTextField field4 = new JTextField();
        JTextField field5 = new JTextField();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Username:"));
        panel.add(field1);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Password:"));
        panel.add(field2);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Repeat Password:"));
        panel.add(field3);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Email address:"));
        panel.add(field4);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Repeat email address:"));
        panel.add(field5);
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Form",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Applet never has a main method , I think you are trying to use JApplet , so even better change your class name from Applet to MyApplet and compile/run it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When launching an applet the `main` method is never called. The entry point for an applet is the [init](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#init%28%29) method:

```
public void init() {
   EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        display();
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help. I knew I was missing something small, and I guess that was it!

Comment: @Reimeus Welcome to the 40K club ;)

Comment: @Reimeus It's been a while since I dealt with applets, but wouldn't `run` be a better method.  As I understand it `init` should be used to "prepare" the applet and `start` is used to let the applet know that the browser has it in focus...(+1 none the less)

Comment: Don't think that would work, nothing works unless you put the code in `init`. See _Threads in Applets_ [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html)